# Kivy:I want window-sized buttons to be stacked on top of the screen

Tags: python, button, layout, kivy, transparent

I want window-sized opaque black button to be stacked on top of the screen 
and the button will be disappear and the screen below will be visible when I press the opaque black button.
I tried but failed all the time.

Below this is my code (`.py`)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock

class First_Screen(Screen, BoxLayout):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class TubucApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

TubucApp().run()
```

and this is my `.kv` file:

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition:
    First_Screen:

<First_Screen>: #<-i want fullscreen-sized opaque black button covers
                #up this screen and will be disappear when i press the button
    name: 'First_Screen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50 
        padding: [50, 50, 50, 50]
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size 
                source: 'image/background.jpg'
        Button:
            id: campustown
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/test.png'
            background_down:'image/test2.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            font_size: 15
            text: 'campus-town'
```

These two images show what I want to accomplish:

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python code

1. Remove `BoxLayout` from `class First_Screen()`

### Snippet - Py

```
class First_Screen(Screen):
    pass
```

## kv file

1. Add a `on_release` event for button
2. Set `background_normal` to `background_down`

### Snippet - kv

```
<First_Screen>:
    name: 'First_Screen'

    Button:
        id: campustown
        background_normal: 'image/test.png'
        background_down: 'image/test2.png'
        border: (0,0,0,0)
        font_size: 15
        text: 'campus-town'
        on_release:
            self.background_normal = self.background_down
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]